# Oracle Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, oracle11g

I am using VS2013 and oracle 11g for database. Oracle developer suite 10g is also installed in my machine. I am trying to connect my database using

```
public void connect()
    {
        try
        {

            conString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=" + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=" + txtBoxProcol.Text + ")(HOST=" + txtBoxHost.Text + ")(PORT=" + txtBoxPort.Text + ")))" + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=" + txtBoxDSource.Text + ")));" + "User Id=" + txtBoxUsr.Text + ";Password=" + txtBoxPaswrd.Text + "enlist=false; pooling=false;";
            con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = conString;
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected Successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (OracleException ex) // catches only Oracle errors
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 1:
                    MessageBox.Show("Error attempting to insert duplicate data.");
                    break;
                case 12545:
                    MessageBox.Show("The database is unavailable.");
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Database error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Clone();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

But I got following error

Oracle Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Changing the conString to

```
 conString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=" + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-3B866TI)(PORT=1521)))" + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL)));" + "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;";
```

is also not working.

My **TNSNAMES.ORA**

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SID = CLRExtProc)
  (PRESENTATION = RO)
)
)

ORCL =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
)
)
```

And **Listener.ora** is

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
(SID_LIST =
(SID_DESC =
  (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
  (ORACLE_HOME = c:\app\hanna\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
  (PROGRAM = extproc)
  (ENVS =      "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:c:\app\hanna\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
)
(SID_DESC=
(GLOBAL_DBNAME = PLSExtProc)
(ORACLE_HOME = c:\app\hanna\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
(SID_NAME = ORCL)
)
)

LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
)
)
```

Oracle_Home in Registry has value = C:\app\hanna\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
I have run lsnrctl stop lsnrctl start commands in cmd. But my connection is not opening. In SQL *PLUS my connection works fine.

Comment: Personally, I'm using the managed assembly that comes from NuGet. No installation at all required on the machine. Also I'm working with connection string settings in app.config only. No obscure .ORA files.

Comment: Try using `conString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=ORCL"`

Comment: Did Jacob's solution worked for you? What does your `lsnrctl status` show? Why is your listener configured to listen for the connections on localhost while you are trying to connect to some DESKTOP-3B866TI? I guess they have different IPs.

Comment: I got Tns could not resolve the connect identifier. @JacobSeleznev

Comment: No jacob's solution doesn't workd. And lsnrtcl status show me Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\hanna\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File c:\app\hanna\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-3B866TI\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))

Comment: rest of status is 
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

@stee1rat

Comment: @UweKeim Provide me the solution.

Comment: Try to change 'DESKTOP-3B866TI' to 'localhost' at first. Also, your database is not registered in the listener, judging by your `lsnrctl status` output. You should have "Service "orcl"" line there. Nevertheless, ORA-12541 tells us that you're trying to connect to the combination of hostname and port that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, if you get "Tns could not resolve the connect identifier" using ORCL as a connect identifier it means that you're editing wrong tnsnames.ora .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86977/discussion-between-hanni-and-stee1rat).